# C# Replacing Numbers With Symbols

Tags: c#

I have an array where user inputs random characters, and i need to replace all numbers with symbol "*". And the worst thing is, that i cant use built in functions! If you can, help please!

Comment: Could you add your code please ? And eventually any errors you might get ?

Comment: And, What do you consider to be built in functions? Regex? ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here if `char.Number` is build in function you should use numbers values from [**ASCII TABLE**](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) for the numbers.

```
string input = "ArrayWithR23andomChar44acter3sWit55hNumbersI6nIt";
char[] array = input.ToCharArray();

for(int i=0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (!char.IsNumber(input[i]))
        continue;

    array[i] = '*';
}
```

Here without `char.IsNumber` you can do it like this:

```
string input = "ArrayWithR23andomChar44acter3sWit55hNumbersI6nIt";
char[] array = input.ToCharArray();

for(int i=0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if ((int)input[i] >= 48 && (int)input[i] <=57)
    {
        array[i] = '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dude! :)

Comment: The number characters 0 to 9 are a reasonable subset of all the number characters, particularly since they need only one UTF-16 code unit (`char`) per character and their code units are in one range.  But, `if (input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')` is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Basically array of characters is nothing than string. You can use this regex to do the job done. For example:

```
string test = "dsad54dsads56dasd7a8s 5468sda";
```

Regex:

```
string t1 = Regex.Replace(test, "[0-9]+", "*");
```

or

```
string t1 = Regex.Replace(test, "[0-9]", "*");
```

The difference is that the first one will replace all consecutive numbers with just one *. The second one will replace every single number with *.

Or, if regex is considered as built in function you can use something like this:

```
char[] t2 = test.Select(c =>
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        return '*';
    }

    return c;
}).ToArray();
```